# Can't get ng-model's value if the value is assigned from another ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have encountered a problem with the model values of angular. I have three scope variables bound to inputs via ng-model via an object called `cfa`: the first is `amt_type`, the second is `amount` and the third is `comp` in which the value for `comp` will depend on the first 2 values, the `amt_type` and `amount`. But the problem is when I tried to display cfa.comp, it doesn't get displayed, and can only be displayed when you typed into the input bound to the `cfa.comp` model. How can I get the value of the ng-model 'cfa.comp' or is there any angular method to fix my problem? Here is the code snippet. Thanks a lot for helping. :)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('sampleCtrl', function($scope){
   $scope.cfa = {};
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller = "sampleCtrl">
  <select ng-model="cfa.amt_type">
     <option value="D">Daily</option>
     <option value="W">Weekly</option>
     <option value="M">Monthly</option>
  </select>
  
  <input type="number" ng-model="cfa.amount" />
  
  <input ng-if="cfa.amt_type == 'D'" type="number" ng-model="cfa.comp" value="{{cfa.amount * 7}}" />
  <input ng-if="cfa.amt_type == 'W'" type="number" ng-model="cfa.comp" value="{{cfa.amount}}" />
  <input ng-if="cfa.amt_type == 'M'" type="number" ng-model="cfa.comp" value="{{cfa.amount / 4}}" />

   {{cfa.comp}}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Additional Info:

The codes above will be repeated several times with different model names and will be used to get the total. Say:

```html
<input ng-if="cfa.amt_type == 'D'" type="number" ng-model="cfa.comp1" value="{{cfa.amount * 7}}" />
    <input ng-if="cfa.amt_type == 'W'" type="number" ng-model="cfa.comp1" value="{{cfa.amount}}" />
    <input ng-if="cfa.amt_type == 'M'" type="number" ng-model="cfa.comp1" value="{{cfa.amount / 4}}" />

<input ng-if="cfa.amt_type == 'D'" type="number" ng-model="cfa.comp2" value="{{cfa.amount * 7}}" />
    <input ng-if="cfa.amt_type == 'W'" type="number" ng-model="cfa.comp2" value="{{cfa.amount}}" />
    <input ng-if="cfa.amt_type == 'M'" type="number" ng-model="cfa.comp2" value="{{cfa.amount / 4}}" />

   <input type="number" ng-model="cfa.total" value="{{cfa.comp1 + cfa.comp2}}" />
```

It is okay for me if I will put it in a div statement or any html tags, but how can I put the value in a variable or any way just to get the total? Thanks :)

Comment: Try declare 'cfa.comp' in your controller like `$scope.cfa = { comp: 0 };`.

Comment: Okay ill try. Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You should make a function that gets called whenever the `amt_type` or `amount` changes, and remove the three inputs. See example below:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('sampleCtrl', function($scope){
   $scope.cfa = {};
   //this function will be bound to the ng-change of the select list and input for amount
   $scope.updateComp = function() {
       if ($scope.cfa.amount) {
           $scope.cfa.comp = $scope.cfa.amount;
           if ($scope.cfa.amt_type == 'D') {
               $scope.cfa.comp = $scope.cfa.amount * 7;
           }
           if ($scope.cfa.amt_type == 'M') {
               $scope.cfa.comp = $scope.cfa.amount / 4;
           }
       }
   };       
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller = "sampleCtrl">
  <select ng-model="cfa.amt_type" ng-change="updateComp()">
     <option value="D">Daily</option>
     <option value="W">Weekly</option>
     <option value="M">Monthly</option>
  </select>
  
  <input type="number" ng-model="cfa.amount" ng-change="updateComp()" />
<div> Comp: {{cfa.comp}} </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh, that seems really nice thanks. Ill try it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your ng-model and value attributes are conflicting for cfa-comp. I personally like the "controller as" and vm syntax, so I will offer that alternative. Also, the result field should be read-only.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('sampleCtrl', function(){
  vm = this;
  
  vm.getComp = function() {
    switch (vm.amt_type) {
        case 'D':
          return vm.amount * 7;
        case 'W':
          return vm.amount;
        case 'M':
          return vm.amount / 4;
        default:
          return undefined;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#comp {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller = "sampleCtrl as ctrl">
  <select ng-model="ctrl.amt_type">
     <option value="D">Daily</option>
     <option value="W">Weekly</option>
     <option value="M">Monthly</option>
  </select>
  
  <input type="number" ng-model="ctrl.amount" />
  
  <span id="comp">{{ctrl.getComp()}}</span
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me :) it displayed the compution by your syntax :) but there is another problem. The codes are repeated several times, say 3 times. all of the computations or the return of getComp function will also be processed to get the total. how should I do it? Thanks again sir. I really appreciate your help

Comment: In your "additional info" code you use the same `cfa.amt_type` and `cfa.amount` value to calculate two different `cfa.compx` values. Since you are using the same controller instance, `cfa.comp1 = cfa.comp2` and `cfa.total = 2 * cfa.comp1`. I suspect that you want an array of objects, each of which contain an `amt_type` and `amount`, at least. I would still recommend using a function for the result, since you get automatic updating and guaranteed integrity that way, but you could pass it an index to say which array element the function is operating on.